# Trying to open chrome with my default user on Selenium using Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, web

I saw in another post about this method of implemnting options..but it still doesn't work.

[image]

Trying to open default user profile instead of a non-logged in chrome tab.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the correct way, you have to add two arguments: `user-data-dir` and `profile-directory`. Moreover, it's better to use `service` instead of `executable_path` cause it's deprecated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\pc1\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 1")

chromedriver_path = '...'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(chromedriver_path), options=options)
```